# Possible to convert xlsx file to csv file with bash script?

Tags: excel, bash, csv, xlsx, data-conversion

So I have a bash script that handles a few things for a java program I wrote. The program writes out an xlsx file and I need to make a copy of that file and convert it to a csv file. Is there any way to do this with a bash script? I'm kind of knee-deep in this already and don't have a lot of time to back out.

Noted: Excel is already installed on the machine

Comment: It needs to be automated. There is a large number of files daily.

Comment: I assume you're using Bash for Windows? I know how to extract and alter individual cells in VBScript/JScript, but I'm not sure that it would be practical to do this for the entire spreadsheet. How big is the spreadsheet?

Comment: @xarxziux Thanks for the reply, I ended up having to modify my original program to solve the issue.